# Execute permissions do not stick on HDFS files

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hdfs

Calling chmod is not sticking for the execute permissions.

```
-bash-3.2$ hadoop dfs -ls /user/myuser/myapp/
Found 1 items
-rw-rw-rw-   3 myuser myuser       2056 2013-09-13 23:14 /user/myuser/myapp/paf-rules.properties
-bash-3.2$ hadoop dfs -chmod ugo+x  /user/myuser/myapp/*
-bash-3.2$ hadoop dfs -ls /user/myuser/myapp/
Found 1 items
-rw-rw-rw-   3 myuser myuser       2056 2013-09-13 23:14 /user/myuser/myapp/paf-rules.properties
```

We get a permissions error in which HDFS complains that the Execute permission is missing:

```
Unable to open readFileFromHdfs based rules file /user/myuser/dqm/paf-rules.properties : org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=myuser, access=EXECUTE, inode="paf-rules.properties":myuser:myuser:rw-rw-rw-
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:960)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:768)
    at com.apple.ist.gbi.edw.etl.fwrk.udf.dqm.UDFPafDqm.readFileFromHdfs(UDFPafDqm.java:81)
    at com.apple.ist.gbi.edw.etl.fwrk.udf.dqm.UDFPafDqm.<init>(UDFPafDqm.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge.initialize(GenericUDFBridge.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF.initializeAndFoldConstants(GenericUDF.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc.newInstance(ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory$DefaultExprProcessor.getXpathOrFuncExprNodeDesc(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory$DefaultExprProcessor.process(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:888)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultRuleDispatcher.dispatch(DefaultRuleDispatcher.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.dispatch(DefaultGraphWalker.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.walk(DefaultGraphWalker.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.startWalking(DefaultGraphWalker.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory.genExprNode(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genExprNodeDesc(SemanticAnalyzer.java:7755)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genSelectPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:2310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genSelectPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:2112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genPostGroupByBodyPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:6165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genBodyPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:6136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:6762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:6702)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:6723)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:7531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:909)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:689)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:557)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=myuser, access=EXECUTE, inode="paf-rules.properties":myuser:myuser:rw-rw-rw-
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkTraverse(FSNamesystem.java:5201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:2027)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getFileInfo(NameNode.java:825)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1092)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at $Proxy6.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at $Proxy6.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:958)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: Is your hadoop security enabled? `dfs.permissions = true` in core-site.xml?

Comment: Yes of course - we would not have this issue if it were disabled. This is a secured env so disabling is not an option.

Comment: So, from the logs it seems you are using Hive, right? And can you share whether the user with which you are executing `hadoop dfs -chmod ugo+x  /user/myuser/myapp/*` has write permission to HDFS?

Comment: @JtheRocker   HI thanks for responding again.  The user running the chmod is the owner of that dir - in fact the dir is under /user/myuser and myuser is the one executing the dfs -chmod command.

Comment: If you are using Apache Hadoop lower than Ver 2.0, can you share with what user(s) you started all your Hadoop daemons like namenode, jobtracker, datanode, secondary namenode, tasktracker?